# How to remove a Windows 7 bootcamp partition from Mojave?

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, windows

I installed Windows 7 via bootcamp several years ago with much older version of macOS but now when I want to delete it via Boot Camp Assistant, it doesn't recognize my bootcamp to remove and also tells me I need to have my whole partition as one, which makes sense.

I read around and can try to remove my Bootcamp partition via Disk Utility but I don't think that would remove the Bootcamp menu and because I'm planning to install Windows 10, I'm not sure how things will go since I have already "a bootcamp" configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: The duplicate is for a EFI booting Windows 10, but the answer will also work in your case.

Comment: when I try to rm -r Boot or Microsoft, it says they don't exist and I'm sure I'm in the correct path (checked with pwd).

I ended up deleting both newly and the Bootcamp via diskutil and trying to install Windows 10 via bootcamp again and I'm facing new problems that I think is better off with a new question than continuing in the comments.

Comment: You have a point. I put a note in the duplicate answer.

Comment: If your Boot Camp install of Windows 10 is using a USB Flash Drive and the Windows ISO is from the October 2018 release, then you should be having problems.